# PHP: sorting multiple arrays by common value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, merge

I have multiple arrays that have a different structure but they all got a column named "round" and "eventnumber". How do I merge them all into one array where they are ordered by an array with the round and then listed by the eventnumber? (I have made the arrays shorter than they really are)

```
$a = 
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [eventid] => 3 [round] => 1 [eventnumber] => 1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [eventid] => 3 [round] => 2 [eventnumber] => 11 )
)

$b = 
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [eventid] => 7 [round] => 1 [eventnumber] => 5 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [eventid] => 8 [round] => 1 [eventnumber] => 3 )
[2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [eventid] => 8 [round] => 2 [eventnumber] => 6 )
)

$c = 
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [eventid] => 6 [round] => 2 [eventnumber] => 2 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [eventid] => 5 [round] => 1 [eventnumber] => 4 )
)
```

Desired Result:

```
$rounds = 
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [eventid] => 3 [round] => 1 [eventnumber] => 1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [eventid] => 8 [round] => 1 [eventnumber] => 3 )
[2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [eventid] => 5 [round] => 1 [eventnumber] => 4 )
[3] => Array ( [id] => 1 [eventid] => 7 [round] => 1 [eventnumber] => 5 ) 
)
Array (
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [eventid] => 6 [round] => 2 [eventnumber] => 2 )
[1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [eventid] => 8 [round] => 2 [eventnumber] => 6 )
[2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [eventid] => 3 [round] => 2 [eventnumber] => 11 )
)
```

I have looked for answers but cant seem to get this to work.
Thanks for taking the time to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replaced your arrays to a,b and c to be simpler. I started by merging the arrays and then sorting them with a comparison function:

```
$a = 
Array ( 
0 => Array ( "id" => 1, "eventid" => 3, "round" => 1, "eventnumber" => 1 ) ,
1 => Array ( "id" => 2, "eventid" => 3, "round" => 2, "eventnumber" => 11 )
);

$b = 
Array ( 
0 => Array ( "id" => 1, "eventid" => 7, "round" => 1, "eventnumber" => 5 ), 
1 => Array ( "id" => 2, "eventid" => 8, "round" => 1, "eventnumber" => 3 ),
2 => Array ( "id" => 3, "eventid" => 8, "round" => 2, "eventnumber" => 6 )
);

$c = 
Array ( 
0 => Array ( "id" => 1, "eventid" => 6, "round" => 2, "eventnumber" => 2 ), 
1 => Array ( "id" => 2, "eventid" => 5, "round" => 1, "eventnumber" => 4 )
);

$result = Array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i){
    if (isset($a[$i])) { 
        array_push($result, $a[$i]); 
    }
    if (isset($b[$i])) { 
        array_push($result, $b[$i]);
    }
    if (isset($c[$i])) { 
        array_push($result, $c[$i]); 
    }
}

function custom_sort($x,$y) {
    if ($x['round'] == $y['round']){
        return $x['eventnumber']>$y['eventnumber'];    
    }

    return $x['round']>$y['round'];
}

usort($result, "custom_sort"); 

print_r($result);
```

To create a `$rounds` array that separates each round in a different array you can do:

```
$rounds = Array();

foreach($result as $row){        
    if (!isset($rounds[$row["round"]])){
        $rounds[$row["round"]] = Array();
    }

    array_push($rounds[$row["round"]], $row); 
}

print_r($rounds);
```

This naturally assumes the previous `$results` array. I didn't join all the code so that its clearer the separating part.

Comment: This was an answer to my question, but after I got it working I realised i needed to do one more thing. They also needed to be sorted by round first

Comment: @Kingfox You mean by round and then eventnumber?

Comment: yes, first it needed to be ordered by the round.. after that each round need to be sorted by the eventnumber (sorry, that I didn't realise this at first)

Comment: I changed the comparison function to meet your new requirements

Comment: Wow, thanks alot! This worked like a charm.. You're the best!

Comment: Last thing: If I wanted to have each round in an array() how would I do that?
(round1 = array[0], round2 = array[1])